# Subscribe method not working when value is changed in the shared service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I had this problem in my project, just the clear it out I created a new project and the problem is more clear. The two components are subscribed to the currentNum Observable, but when it is updated from component1, the subscription is not working in the component2 or the  otherwise.

```
//SharedService
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
    
    private myNum = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
    currentNum = this.myNum.asObservable()

    setNum(number: number) {
        console.log("setNumber: ", number)
        this.myNum.next(number);
    }
}
```

```
// Component 1
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../services/SharedService.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component1',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './component1.component.html',
  styleUrl: './component1.component.css',
  providers: [SharedService]
})
export class Component1Component {
  componentNumber = 0;
  constructor(private service: SharedService) {
    this.service.currentNum.subscribe((number) => {
      this.componentNumber = number;
      console.log("component 1 number updated by subscription.")
    })
  }
  setNumber() {
    this.service.setNum(1);
  }
}
```

```
// Component 2
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../services/SharedService.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component2',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './component2.component.html',
  styleUrl: './component2.component.css',
  providers: [SharedService]
})
export class Component2Component {

  componentNumber = 0;
  constructor(private service: SharedService) {
    this.service.currentNum.subscribe((number) => {
      this.componentNumber = number;
      console.log("component 2 number updated by subscription.")
    })
  }
  setNumber() {
    this.service.setNum(2);
  }
}
```

I just updated Angular CLI to 17, I hope it is not the issue, because in my previous projects I had the same structure of shared service and it worked well.

Comment: You provide the service in both components which mean they have different instances of the same service.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much